# Need help in proving an inclusion between some subspaces of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

The following question was first posted on Math.Stackexchange.com but unfortunately I didn’t get any answer. This might be obvious for many researchers but I can’t see how this is so, thus I am asking it here:

Let $V$ be a closed subspace of $B(H,K)$ such that $xy^*z \in V$ for all $x,y,z \in V$. Let $I$ be an ideal $(IV^*V+VV^*I \subset I)$ of $V$. Let $C(I)$ denotes the $C^{\ast}$-algebra generated by $II^{\ast}$. In a paper the following inclusion is stated without proof:

> $VI^{\ast} \subset C(I)$

I don’t see how this can be true, since $C(I)$ is generated by $II^{\ast}$ therefore how could $VI^*$ be included inside $C(I)$?

Comment: What paper is this from?  I don't immediately see the answer.

Comment: @NikWeaver: This inclusion is stated in proposition $2.2.4$ in Manmohan Kaur’s PhD thesis. She has used this result crucially in showing that $A(I)$ is ideal of $A(V)$, where $A(V)$ denotes linking $C^{\star}$- algebra of TRO $V$. Do you think this result is true?

Comment: Why don't you just email her for an explanation? Assuming it isn't explained in the thesis.

Comment: @NikWeaver: I found a counter example on math.stackexchange.com. Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that there are extra assumptions in this part of Kaur's thesis, which are used to justify this inclusion and the subsequent result that $A(I)$ is an ideal in $A(V)$. It would help if you quote the whole statement of Prop 2.2.4

Comment: By the way, it it is good practice to link to the MSE question, so that people here can see what has been said over there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504653/need-help-in-proving-an-inclusion-between-some-subspaces-of-operators Likewise, at MSE you should link to this MO post, so that the people responding at MSE can see what has been said in comments here

Comment: @YemonChoi:  Here is the statement: “Let $I$ be closed ideal of $V$ then $V/I$ is TRO”.

Comment: @MathLover think about how your last comment would be received by someone asking for more details and context. Does the thesis not specify what $V$ is? Yemon wonders if there are extra assumptions in the thesis and your comment does not answer this.

Comment: @NikWeaver (and MathLover) looking at the JFA 2002 paper of Kaur and Ruan which seems to be the only publication based on her thesis, the basic facts about the Cstar algebras associated to TROs seem to predate her thesis, and if you look at the references in that paper, then it seems like you might find further explanation in this paper of Hamana: http://doi.org/10.15099/00003027

Comment: @NikWeaver BTW, Nik, perhaps you could leave a comment for Martin A over on MSE so that we are not getting duplicated effort?

Comment: @NikWeaver: As far as I have read her thesis there is no extra assumption on $V$, it was just assumed to be a TRO.

Comment: @YemonChoi: I will check out this paper of Hamana. Btw, I was mainly interested in a fact which I have posted recently here on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505790/trying-to-prove-a-subset-is-ideal-of-a-c-ast-algebra. You may like to see it.